# Non-linear Ordinary Differential Equation solution method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I obtain the following solution to the following non-linear ordinary differential equation:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^{2}-\frac{GM}{R}=E
$$

Where $E<1$. The solution has the form:

$$
R(\theta)=R_{0}(1-\cos\theta)
$$
$$
t(\theta)=t_{0}(\theta-\sin\theta)
$$

It is an equation which crops up in cosmology and galaxy formation, in terms of spherical collapse. But often, this solution is just given. No actual method for arriving at this solution.

Comment: can you say something to the variables?

Comment: I'm assuming something like $dt=Rd\theta$ but I'm not sure. If you don't know then I suggest there's no point helping me. I need someone who has come across this before.

Comment: Based on your other question, your solution is missing $t(\theta)$, since it's parametric

Comment: Yes that is also a solution. I've added that, so would you know how to proceed?

Comment: Wasn't this asked just a few days ago?

Comment: Sorry, but I'll let you know if I figure it out. Also, you've just asked this, so reason to repost the question.

Comment: Because I wanted to add some more specifics, have deleted the old question.